# FPDF error: Unsupported image type (while using header to define image)

Tags: php, fpdf, pdftk

So I have an image string that I insert into a webpage with a header telling the browser it is an image.

So a page would look like this:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    echo $image_data;
?>
```

`http://website.com/randomString.png` is used to grab the image (using .htaccess)

When I use the following code, I get the error `FPDF error: Unsupported image type`

```
$imagePath = file_get_contents("http://website.com/".$randomString.".png");
$pdf->Image($imagePath,159,185,27);
```

Does anyone know what I can do to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `Image` with `MemImage` (and copy class from the listing below or copy the functions by itself), otherwise it wants to read image from file.

http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script45.php

Comment: Ah okay, let me include this MemImage and see if it works, thanks!

Comment: Look at the link and copy the function from there.

Comment: I use `$pdf = new FPDI();` and not `$pdf = new PDF_MemImage();` like it asks me to so I just have to figure out how to incorporate the function into the existing fpdf page

Comment: It does not matter, you can extend class PDI as `class PDF_MemImage extends FPDI` and run everything in the same way.

Comment: I copy and paste everything at the bottom of my `fpdf.php` page and I just get a `Call to undefined method FPDI::MemImage()`

Comment: @bryan because it is not static.. Ok, give me some time, I'll download libraries and write a code.

Comment: No worries Cheery, I just copied the `function MemImage()` into my fpdf class, `VariableStream` class at the end of the fpdf.php file, and added `stream_wrapper_register('var', 'VariableStream');` to the first line of the function and it seems to be working nicely. Thanks for your help!